# LINQ join to collection using index

Tags: c#, linq

We have a basic collection containing strings and we would like to use LINQ to join to this collection based on an int returned from the database (in the same linq statement) but the collection does not have an "index" as such, so we were hoping we could simply reference the index of the collection ie. where the item is placed within the collection.

In simple terms outside of linq we would do

```
string MyString = MyCollection[MyIndex];
```

but this is not supported inside LINQ.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which Linq-provider are you using?

Comment: Is your question that you want to select every nth character in each string?

Answer (score 2):

To refer on index in LINQ query you can leverage following overloads of `Select()` or `Where()`

```
collection.Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
          .Select(p => /* now you can refer to p.item and p.index */);

collection.Where((item, index) => index == indexFromDb);
```

Also LINQ provides [ElementAt()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb299233.aspx)/[ElementAtOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386.aspx) methods which allows accessing a single item by an index

Comment: This is within an edf linq statement in c#.  Was hoping there was a "join" type method?!

Comment: Look here for Linq join operators: [LINQ - Join Operators](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9)

Comment: When we try and use "ElementAt" we receive this at runtime :- LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ElementAt[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String], Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Porbably te function ```ElementAt()``` cannot be translated to an SQL query, it only works on objects.

Comment: Yes exactly, anyone have any other ideas?  Thought it would be simple to link the integer value of one entity table to a local collection!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean your Linq collection is not indexable (accessible by an index, like `MyCollection[0]`), you could take the resulting collection and call `ToList()` or `ToArray()` on it. The resulting list (or array) does have an indexer.

Comment: We are using an ObservableCollection so it does have an enumerator but doesnt have a specific index property we can reference in the linq "join"

Comment: I have explained my problem a little better here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273142/join-collection-inside-an-entity-linq-statement

Comment: Ok, but next time please update your original question instead of creating a new one.