# Join collection inside an Entity LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

This problem related to LINQ-to-entity.

I posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269842/linq-join-to-collection-using-index) but it got confusing without an answer, so I am providing an example and a new shout for help.

I have a class "Colors" containing an `ObservableCollection` which has two members, `Index` and `Name` and populated like :

0 - Red 
 1 - Blue
 
 2 - Green

and I have a database table containing a list of integers of my favorite colors.  I would like to return a query with both the integer value of my favorite color and also the matching name (returned by the observablecollection) based on the index value stored in the database.

This statement in isolation works fine and returns my color name :-

`string ColorName = Colors.Names.Where(x => x.Index == 1).FirstOrDefault().Name;`

but when included within the LINQ-to-entity query :-

```
var query = from c in context.FavoriteColor
select (new Item
    {
        Id = c.Id,
      ColorName = Colors.Names.Where(x => x.Index == c.ColorIndex).FirstOrDefault().Name
    });
```

I get this error :

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'blah blah'. Only primitive
>   types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this
>   context.

I understand that maybe the object is being returned within the LINQ statement but I thought by specifying the .Name notation on the end, which is a string member, it would use that and assign it to "ColorName", alas not.

Comment: Please include "blah blah blah" I can only assume that is "ObservableCollection<T>" well only in compiler speak.

Comment: Aron - it's the type contained within the observablecollection. Thanks

Comment: EF can't serialise Color into SQL. You need to do the look up in .net rather in SQL.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly the conclusion I was coming to.  I fear I will have to iterate the collection and update the color within that loop.  Just seems a little messy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
var query = from c in context.FavoriteColor
            select new { c.Id, c.ColorIndex };
var result = from c in query.ToList()
             select new Item
             {
                 Id = c.Id,
                 ColorName = Colors.Names.Where(x => x.Index == c.ColorIndex).FirstOrDefault().Name
             };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a CLR object in a database query. LINQ-to-Entities is saying you can't do that. Get the color name after the query has completed.

```
var dbItems = context.FavoriteColor.Select(c => new {
    c.Id,
    c.ColorIndex
).ToList();

var items = dbItems.Select(item => new Item {
    Id = item.Id,
    ColorName = Colors.Names.Where(x => x.Index == item.ColorIndex).First().Name
})
```

The idea here is that the call to `ToList` hits the database and returns the results in a CLR object. That object can then be used like any other object.

Comment: being new to LINQ-to-entities I was hoping I could join these disparate data sources but it seems not! Thank you for your help, will give it a try.

Comment: I get the same issue with the second of your linq statements so i think I am going to create a new collection from my query and iterate that to update the textual value of color, unless there is a more efficient way.

Comment: @xnetdude - What exactly is the issue? What is the exception being thrown?

Comment: Hi - i received the same error as previously mentioned in my op but I dont think I was doing it correctly.<br/>  I have resolved the issue now by moving the code into the setter of the object being created during the linq.  I am now doing to "look up" to the clr object in there.<br/>Thank you for your help.